# Conda not using .condarc in root environment

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

We are using a centralized conda install. The Continuum docs say:

> A .condarc file may also be located in the root environment, in which case it overrides any in the home directory.

Perhaps I'm not understanding what "root environment" means. I put a `.condarc` at the top level in the conda install directory. However anytime I run any conda operation (including just `conda list`), it overrides the one in the root environment and creates one in my home directory.

Answer (score 0):

With the newest version of conda under debian I copy the config file as such

```
root@e42dc1ece1e3:/home/jonb4# ls -la /opt/conda/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  155 Sep 28 11:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   19 Jun  4 08:23 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1058 Sep 28 11:53 .condarc
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root 3699 May 12 20:59 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  4 08:24 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  4 08:24 conda-meta
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    6 Jun  4 08:24 envs
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   18 Jun  4 08:24 etc
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  314 Jun  4 08:24 include
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jun  4 08:24 lib
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root 4096 Jun  4 08:24 pkgs
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   29 Jun  4 08:24 share
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   71 Jun  4 08:24 ssl
```

Then as a user my correct config settings are read without a problem.